# Laravel 5.1 : Choose migration folder according to app config

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

Basically, I want to place two different folders in `app/database/migrations` folder and load migrations only from one of them

```
 - migrations
     - folder 1
     - folder 2
```

And when I running the `php artisan migrate` I want it to look into my `config/app.php` and determine which files need to be executed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yea you can migrate from specific folders. Just add **`--path`** when you run migration.

like: `php artisan migrate --path='database/migrations/folder1'`

Comment: Yes, that is what I do now, but I'm really need to automate that process.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure we can do with your Laravel version (5.1), from 5.3 Laravel supports `loadMigrationsFrom` method.

By adding below line to `boot` method from `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class, I registered custom migration path for placing all trigger definitions.

```
public function boot()
{
  // Other registrations

  $this->loadMigrationsFrom(database_path('migrations/triggers'));
}
```